# Can't get pack Uri to work

Tags: wpf, uri

I've got a WPF application I'm building.  The solution contains a WPF control library project called CustomControls.  There's a folder under the CustomControls project folder called Layouts.  There's an XML file in that folder called OnscreenLayout.xml.  The Build Action property for this file is set to Embedded Resource.

I'm trying to load that file into a stream in the code behind and pass the stream on to a method of a third party library class.  The code in question looks like this:

```
OnscreenKeyboard.DefaultLayout = FPS.VirtualKeyboard.KeyboardLayout.Create( 
    App.GetResourceStream( 
        new Uri( @"/CustomControls;component/Layouts/OnscreenLayout.xml", 
            UriKind.Relative ) ).Stream );
```

When this code runs, it throws an IOException with the message

```
Cannot locate resource 'layouts/onscreenlayout.xml'.
```

I've even tried using this string for the Uri:

```
@"pack://application:,,,/CustomControls;component/Layouts/OnscreenLayout.xml"
```

But no joy.  What am I doing wrong?

Edit:  I have even tried changing the build action for the file from "Embedded Resource" to "Resource" and it still doesn't work.

Thanks

Tony

Comment: Have you tried to use reflector or something similar to check with resources you have in your assembly, and how they are really named? In general go for the pack url and "resource" build action, then it works.

Comment: @MartinMoser: Yes, I've done that. The Uri looks right to me.  I'm at a loss.

Comment: It's not just '.xaml' not '.xml' is it?

Comment: @Phil: No, it's not a .xaml file, it's an .xml file.

Comment: After speaking with my boss and another guy who just started today & has some experience with WPF, what I ended up doing was switching the Build Action back to Embedded resource and accessing the file through the 'Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` method.  In the window in the other assembly, I iterate all of the `Assemblies` using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies` until I find the one with the file, then I use the same method to get it.  It works.  I'd still like to know why the Uri didn't work, though.

Comment: Just tried it with a .xml file, same uri, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only **Content** and **Resource** build actions are valid for resource files used in WPF application.

Please avoid other build actions such as **Embedded Resource** - this will work as well with appropriate API, but it is not favored by WPF.